# OnClick event implementation on ListView and CustomListViewAdapter

Tags: android

I would like to share my concern and get some feedback from you.

I am trying to implement customized ListView and the requirements are,

1. Each raw should contain an imageView, a textView and one Button.
2. When Button is clicked, should open a homepage.
3. When clicked on elsewhere in the row, should show detailed description.

Here's what I did,

```
MainActivity.java

KwoolyCompanyAdapter adapter = new KwoolyCompanyAdapter(this, R.layout.listviewitem_company,list);

listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DescriptionActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Company", (String)listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

As you can see, To do requirement 3, I have put the setOnItemClickListener to the ListView.

For the custom Ui, I have created adapter called KwoolyCompanyAdapter which extends BaseAdapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int pos = position;
    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(itemLayout, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(list.get(pos));

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, GetCompanyResourceId(list.get(pos)));
        imageView.setImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable);

        Button button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(GetCompanyHomepageURL(list.get(pos))));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

I have created an imageView, a textView and a button and appended setOnClickListener to the button only.

The problem is.. pressing the button raise a event and work as expected.
But when I click elsewhere, nothing happens.

I can make it work by putting OnClick event handler to the imageView and textView but I think this is not desirable because, every time we need to fix a behavior after a "click", we need to fix the KwoolyCompanyAdapter.

How do you think?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you need `View.OnClickListenre` for? just use `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` instead

Answer (score 0):

By default, all Android controls are focusable.

You must remove it by adding `android:focusable="false"` on all of your controls in list itemview, but this has a problem, because your button click event not working. Right way to do this is to block focusability from the itemview root ViewGroup by adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <!-- Your child views -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The magic keyword "blocksDescendants" works! Don't know exactly what that is.. but it is good start to study. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove OnItemClickListener, and add OnClickListener to convertView in adapter with the same logic.

Comment: i would rather remove OnClickListener and add OnItemClickListener, OnItemClickListener is for listening listview clicks

Comment: Great! This works, too. What @Hamed tought me is..we can define OnClick event handler at outside of the CutomizedAdapterView class, and your suggestion enables me to define OnClick event handler inside the customized class. Thanks!